# How to access sqlite file on host machine from a Docker container using docker-compose?

Tags: sqlite, docker, docker-compose

I have

- a Flask server running in Docker using docker-compose.
- a sqlite file stores on the host machine.

I want to access the sqlite file from the docker image with the up to date change of sqlite file.

Comment: Not sure how your docker-compose.yml looks like. But you can achieve your goal by mounting the volumes

Comment: correct me if im wrong, i think mounting by volume gives you a "snapshot" of the file when the image is created but not the up to date version

Comment: It will sync with your local DB file continuously

Answer (score 1):

If you have the file on the host machine, you can simply mount that file inside the container, using the `-v` option.
The changes performed by the container on the file will be visible on the host.

Quick proof of concept:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── the-file
```

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  the-flask:
    image: python
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/the-file:/mnt/the-file
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

Compose up, get the container ID, then append some text from the container to the file mounted from the host:

```
docker-compose up -d 

docker exec <container-id> sh -c 'echo "Contend added from container" >> /mnt/the-file'
```

The file on the host:

```
cat the-file 
Initial content
Contend added from container
```